# Class Based Views UpdateView django different type of model

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

how can I change model in UpdateView for different type of users? I have `Student` and `Teacher` inherited from `AbstractBaseUser`, and I need edit for for them

```
class EditUser(UpdateView):
    success_url = '/success/'
    template_name = 'edit-profile.html'
    model = Teacher (I need to choose this Teacher or Student)
```

I know about `get_template_names(self)` method or `get_success_url(self)`,  but can not find any `get_model` method.
I need somethng like:

```
def get_model_name(self):
    if self.request.user.user_type == 'teacher':
        return Teacher
    if self.request.user.user_type == 'student':
        return Studend
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#singleobjectmixin):

> `model`
>
> The model that this view will display data for. Specifying `model = Foo`
>   is effectively the same as specifying `queryset = Foo.objects.all()`,
>   where `objects` stands for `Foo`’s default manager.
>
> `queryset`
>
> A `QuerySet` that represents the objects. If provided, the value of
>   `queryset` supersedes the value provided for `model`.
>
> `get_queryset()`
>
> Returns the queryset that will be used to retrieve the object that
>   this view will display. By default, `get_queryset()` returns the value
>   of the `queryset` attribute if it is set, otherwise it constructs a
>   `QuerySet` by calling the `all()` method on the model attribute’s default
>   manager.

So, all you need is redefine `get_queryset` method